# ソースコードも一緒にAzure側にデプロイする方法

Tags: c#, visual-studio, azure

Visual StudioからAzureにデプロイすると、Azure側にはdllファイルのみがあり、ソースコードのcsファイルがありません。ソースコードも一緒にAzure側にデプロイする方法はないでしょうか？

環境は、Visual Studio 2015 Community です。

よろしくお願いします。

Answer (score 0, accepted):

コードビハインドを使わずに直接コードを書いてみてはどうでしょうか？

参考
http://www.atmarkit.co.jp/ait/articles/0207/18/news001.html